# Блокировка (?) парсинга

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер

Суть проблемы:
Создал простейший парсер, заимствующий у Кинопоиска названия фильмов с определённой страницы. Первые 5 запросов успешно обрабатываются сайтом и я получаю желанные названия фильмов, но после пятого, код выводит пустой список.
Скорее всего сайт блокирует подобные запросы и не даёт спарсить информацию (по-моим предположениям появляется капча, но это неточно). Если заходить на сайт из браузера, то всё работает, также пробовал пропинговать - работает.
Из-за чего возникает проблемы? Посоветуйте как её решить? 
P.S. Если что-то не так написал - извиняйте

```
headers = {'accept': accept,'user-agent': user-agent}

base_url = url

def parse (base_url, headers):
    session = requests.Session()
    request = session.get(base_url, headers = headers)
    if request.status_code == 200:
        soup = bs(request.content, 'html.parser')
        divs = soup.find_all('div', attrs = {'class': foo})
        for div in divs:
            name = divs.find('p', attrs = {'p': bar}).text
            print(name)
    else: 
        print('ERROR')

parse(base_url, headers)
```

Comment: Отладкой решить. Смотр, какой ответ прислал сайт и действуй соответствующим образом. Либо в своей же проге смотри, либо fiddler поставь.

Comment: @Qwertiy как узнать какой ответ "присылает сайт"? Никаких ошибок при запуске не возникает, код просто выводит пустой список...

Comment: @Chaddydaddy сделать `print(request.content)` очевидно

Comment: @andreymal cmd выплёвывает огромный html код, что-то я ничего не понимаю...

Comment: @Chaddydaddy вот и читайте в этом html-коде, есть ли в нём нужный вам контент, а если нет, то тогда что есть вместо него и чем он отличается от браузерного html-кода

Comment: Ещё может быть, что дополнительные результаты генерируются JavaScript-ом уже после загрузки страницы. Тут уже Selenium надо применять.